# React Bootstrap Carousel not displaying

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a React application that utilizes the Bootstrap Carousel. I followed [this documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/) and this is what I came up with:

```
import React from 'react'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'

function SplashScreen() {  
    return (
        <div className="Panel" style={{height: "100vh"}}>
            <Carousel>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src='...'
                        alt="First slide"
                    />
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src='...'
                        alt="Second slide"
                    />
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        src='...'
                        alt="Third slide"
                    />
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SplashScreen
```

I must be missing something because when I compile, this is all that is displayed:

[image: It looks to be a blank list]

If anyone has a solution to this or maybe some better documentation I would appreciate it!

EDIT: This is the console when installing react-bootstrap
[image: Console]

EDIT 2: I got it working. I had to add this to App.js.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: The code works fine with me.  Seems like you are missing some dependency for bootstrap. Can you do npm install react-bootstrap@latest and attach a screenshot of that?

Comment: I added the screenshot @Dhruva-404

Comment: I got it working. Thank you though :) @Dhruva-404